# Spring Security all rolles except anonymous

Tags: spring-security, anonymous

hi i have an spring security application

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" />
    <form-login authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler" authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" login-page="${loginUrl}" authentication-failure-url="${loginUrl}" />
    <logout logout-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true" success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler" />
    <anonymous enabled='false'/>
</http>
```

but anonymous user is not intercepted, how can i allow all roles but not ROLE_ANONYMOUS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY`:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
```

You can do the same thing using SpEL expression:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    ...        
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />        
    ...
</http>
```

All available expressions are listed [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/).
In general SpEL expressions are more flexible.